# Destruct using titles

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I have answered a few questions using destructing, I just want to take this one to the next level

I want to not use reduce in this example but pure destructing if at all possible

So the data's first row contains the attribute names of the object, How can I use that to be DRY

i.e. I hoped for

```
const obj = data.slice(1).map((titles) => ({ titles }) )
```

or similar

So this works, but I miss one more step:

```js
const data = [
    ["fruits","frozen","fresh","rotten"],
    ["apples",884,494,494],
    ["oranges",4848,494,4949],
    ["kiwi",848,33,33]
]
const titles = data[0]; // not used below but I want to use it
const obj = data.slice(1).map(([fruits,frozen,fresh,rotten]) => ({ fruits,frozen,fresh,rotten }) )
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Use reduce method of array to create object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the entries for an object.

```js
const
    data = [["fruits", "frozen", "fresh", "rotten"], ["apples", 884, 494, 494], ["oranges", 4848, 494, 4949], ["kiwi", 848, 33, 33]],
    mapWith = keys => values => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, values[i]])),
    getArray = ([keys, ...data]) => data.map(mapWith(keys)),
    array = getArray(data);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Old simpler example

```js
const data = [
  ["fruits", "frozen", "fresh", "rotten"],
  ["apples", 884, 494, 494],
  ["oranges", 4848, 494, 4949],
  ["kiwi", 848, 33, 33]
]
const titles = data[0];

const obj = data.slice(1).map(
  arr => Object.fromEntries(
    titles.map( 
      (t, i) => [t, arr[i]] 
    )
  )
);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Okeee, Now I have to figure out what you did there ;)))

Comment: I saved the first one because I figured it out. Then you upped the ante somewhat. How performant is the new example? Looks like a lot of processing

Comment: not more. it just splits the array and gets the first row for keys and the rest for iterating as values.

Comment: I do not however understand the TWO fat arrow syntax: `mapWith = keys => values =>`

Comment: that is just a closure over the parameter and return a function at the end with another parameter.

Comment: Oi... Hard to grasp :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a curried version of `zip` which is similar to `Object.fromEntries` except that it doesn't take pairs but a list of keys and a list of values and pairs are formed based on indexes:

```js
zip(['a','b'], [1,2]);
//=> {a: 1, b: 2})
```

Because it is curried you can use it in your map and avoid hardcoding titles:

```js
const data = [
    ["fruits","frozen","fresh","rotten"],
    ["apples",884,494,494],
    ["oranges",4848,494,4949],
    ["kiwi",848,33,33]
]

const zip =
  keys =>
    values =>
      Object.fromEntries
        ( keys.map((k, i) => [k, values[i]])
        );
        
const from_csv =
  ([titles, ...rows]) =>
    rows.map(zip(titles));

console.log(
  from_csv(data)
);
```

Comment: Thanks - interesting example

Comment: @mplungjan Since you don't seem to be keen on `Array#reduce` I modified the `zip` function to use `Object.fromEntries`. So that the map is constructed "natively". Unless there's many pairs, it's unlikely to be noticeable. But there you go ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce`, but you can't really destruct...

```js
const data = [
    ["fruits","frozen","fresh","rotten"],
    ["apples",884,494,494],
    ["oranges",4848,494,4949],
    ["kiwi",848,33,33]
]
const titles = data[0];
const obj = data.slice(1).map((row) => titles.reduce((agg, cur, index) => {
   agg[cur] = row[index];
   return agg;
}, {}));
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks - interesting example - I really wanted to not reduce

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    ["fruits","frozen","fresh","rotten"],
    ["apples",884,494,494],
    ["oranges",4848,494,4949],
    ["kiwi",848,33,33]
];
const [titles, ...rest] = data;
const obj = rest.map((xs) => {
  const o = {};
  xs.forEach((x,i) => o[titles[i]] = x);
  return o;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the normal one. It can be rewritten as a reduce too